# Naming convention passing function as prop to other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I struggle to name things in react when passing function to other components as props, let's look at code below

```
import { getUsers } from './userApi
export default class App {

  state = { users: [] }

  async _load = () => {
     const users = await getUsers()
     this.setState({users})
  }
  render(){
    return <Users onload={this._load} users={this.state.users} />
  }
}
```

It's still ok if you have one level of passing, you can access props.onload, but what if you need to pass onload function into other component in `<Users />`, how would you name it?

Comment: i would have named it `loadUsers()` but imo `_load()` is also self explanatory - maybe smth like `loadUsersAndSetState()`

Comment: @messerbill so you have multiple _load() passing down to children of component, is that ok?

Comment: Function names starting with `_` are supposed to be private. Also, `on....` gives the impression that, that function is a callback function.

Comment: if you wanted to pass this `_load()` method to a child of `<Users>` component you need to access the relevant `prop` of `Users` - in your case this is `onload`. I.e. template code inside `Users` could look like `<div><myChild onload={this.props.onload?this.props.onload:null}>`

Comment: Its better to have a name that is consistent from top to bottom, also if the child doesn't make use of onload and just passes it down to its child, you could simply use rest spread syntax like const {something, ...rest} = this.props; and pass {...rest} to the children

Comment: Personally I just name the prop the same as the function. It's a nice and easy rule and you don't have to worry about remembering all those names as you pass them down.

Comment: @theJuls make sense, now I'm trying to do the same.